# Cascading Power Mux

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, multiplexer

[image]

I have used power mux ICs before but I decided to try to cascade them to choose between 3 sources rather than 2. +V_USB_AUX works when plugged in and nothing else plugged in. +V_USB_MAIN works when plugged in and nothing else plugged in. However, +V_DIN does not work when plugged in and nothing else plugged in. I have not plugged in multiple sources at the same time because I wanted to test everything by itself first.

Now when I say it does not work, I mean that I can measure +V for a moment's time on my logic analyzer (I don't have a scope handy) and then its gone. This keeps up indefinitely. It is almost like the source I am pulling from can't handle an in-rush of charging the 10uF caps, goes into protection, and then tries again. Everything else on +V is a typical application of a STM32 dev board circuit (bypass caps, small filtering inductor, etc.). Before I get my setup going tomorrow to test a source on the +V_DIN net that can source a better in rush of current (like my bench top power supply), I wanted to post this circuit here to see if perhaps cascaded is something odd to do and there was a 'gotchja' I was not aware of.

Thanks for taking a look!

Edit 1: I tried to remove C32 and replace it with a 1uF. Still getting power fluctuations on U9's output when only using +V_DIN. I have now bypassed that circuit together as I think my rework might have killed U9. I wired it up like below.

[image]

When I try to now only use +V_DIN, the same behavior occurs for U8. The output fluctuates. In the past I had +V_DIN and +V_USB swapped but I switched for this revision to switch the priority around. Perhaps I should switch them back via rework to see if I can get back to where I was in the last revision.

If anyone has any ideas on why it would fluctuate, please let me know! :)

Edit 2: So I swapped +V_DIN and +V_USB_(both). Works well now. I am not sure which one is the priority now but I will try later. I still have no idea why +V_DIN flickered when +V_USB_(both) doesn't. Still need to research why.